# How to undo operations on the ipad

Tags: ipad, undo

To undo operations on the iphone I can shake it.
This is a bit difficult for the ipad. Which is the way on this device to undo operations?

Thank you

Comment: Questions about iPad are off-topic on super User. I suggest you direct your future questions to our sister site dedicated to [Apple products](http://apple.stackexchange.com/), currently in public beta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access undo and redo from the keyboard; or you can shake it.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions. Especially if you vote to close them.